# from_float function or associated item not found in `FixedU128`

Tags: fixed-point-math

I'm trying to use fixed point variable in my substrate pallet. Here's my import:

```
use frame_support::sp_runtime::FixedU128;
```

and when I try to do this

```
let some_var = FixedU128::from_float(0.1515151f64);
```

here's what I get:

```
 let some_var = FixedU128::from_float(0.1515151f64);
                           ^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `FixedU128`
```

Which is definitely not true, because `from_float` is there in `FixedU128` as shown here: https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/sp_runtime/struct.FixedU128.html#method.from_float

I guess I'm doing something wrong, pls help.

Comment: It worked for me. Is it possible you are using a very old Substrate version?

Comment: I'm using branch = "polkadot-v0.9.17"

Here's excerpt from my toml: 
sp-runtime = { default-features = false, version = "5.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.17" }

Comment: cargo clean didn't solve it

Comment: Here's what's strange: 
this error only comes up when I build the whole project with cargo check or cargo build --release, but doesn't come up when I do cargo check -p pallet-template

Answer (score 3):

The `from_float` function is only available for tests and compiling with `std`, and thus is not usable in the runtime itself:

From [`primitives/arithmetic/src/fixed_point.rs`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/primitives/arithmetic/src/fixed_point.rs#L414)

```
#[cfg(any(feature = "std", test))]
pub fn from_float(x: f64) -> Self {
    Self((x * (<Self as FixedPointNumber>::DIV as f64)) as $inner_type)
}
```

You should use one of the other available APIs to get the number you want.

Comment: Shawn, thank you! Which API would you suggest as an example?

Comment: `.151515` is approximately `15 / 99`, so I would use: `FixedU128::saturating_from_rational(15, 99)`, or `FixedU128::from_inner(151_515_100_000_000_000)`, which should be the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi If we are doing ```FixedU128::saturating_from_rational(5, 10)``` then I'm getting 0 instead of 0.5? how can i get 0.5?

Comment: Please open a new question for this. If you have some rust code, post it, and post your expected result, and we can fix it for you.

Comment: I get perfect results:

`use sp_runtime::{FixedPointNumber, FixedU128}; let half = FixedU128::saturating_from_rational(5, 10); let result = half * FixedU128::saturating_from_integer(5); println!("{:?}, {:?}", half, result);`

and the output: `FixedU128(0.500000000000000000), FixedU128(2.500000000000000000)`